# MenuItem alpha value lost after orientation change

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

**The Problem**

On Android versions < 4.1, the alpha value of the MenuItem is getting reset after an orientation change, BUT it remains disabled.

**The code I'm using**

DetailsFragment.java

```
public class DetailsFragment extends SherlockFragment {
private MenuItem miEmail;
...
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    miEmail= menu.findItem(R.id.menu_email);
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
   }

private void populateDetails(final Detail oDetail) {
    //disable email button if dealer doesn't have option
    if(!oDetail.bShowSAM){
        miEmail.setEnabled(false);
        miEmail.getIcon().setAlpha(50);
    }
    ...
    }
}
```

MyManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.DetailsActivity"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" 
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation">
</activity>
```

**What I expect to happen**

When the orientation changes, miEmail is still disabled and the alpha value is still at 50.

**What is actually happening**

When testing on older devices(2.3,4.0), the MenuItem is remaining disabled but the alpha value is getting reset to the default value. When testing with my devices that are >4.1, it is working as expected.

**What I've tried**

*Googling the problem.......*

I've tried to avoid using the `android:configChanges="..."` and handling the data through `savedInstanceState`, but I've learned you can't make the MenuItem serializable/parciable, thus not allowing me to pass it through outState bundle object.

I'm fairly new to Android development and I feel as though there is a trivial way of handling this `MenuItem`, but I cannot figure how else to handle it.

***What do you think is the issue?***

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Dont set the icon alpha on your custom function, instead, set it on OnPrepareOptionsMenu (with a suitable conditional). You can pass a boolean on savedinstancestate saying whether it should be grayed or not.

In your populateDetails function, you would call invalidateOptionsMenu() to make android remake the action bar icons. Example:

```
private boolean buttonEnabled;
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem miEmail= menu.findItem(R.id.menu_email);
    if (buttonEnabled) {
        miEmail.setEnabled(true);
        miEmail.getIcon().setAlpha(255);
    }else{
        miEmail.setEnabled(true);
        miEmail.getIcon().setAlpha(50);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
private void populateDetails(final Detail oDetail) {
    //disable email button if dealer doesn't have option
    if(!oDetail.bShowSAM){
        buttonEnabled = false;
        InvalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
    ...
    }
}
```

If you are using the support library for compatibility, use supportInvalidateOptionsMenu instead.

By the way, never use the orientation tag to "fix" the problem, the issue will still appear if you quit the app for a long time and then try to open it. (android pauses the activity initially and will stop it after a while)